# Two parallel conv2d layers (keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want two build a neural network that takes two separate matrices with same dimensions (for example grey-scale images) as input, and outputs a value between -1 and 1 (probably tanh).

I would like to build the network so that there are two seperate convolutional layers as inputs. Each one takes one matrix(or image). An then that these one are combined in a following layer. So i want it to look something like that:

[image]

My first question is can i do this in keras (or if not in tensorflow)?
The second Question is? Does it make sense?
Because I could also very easy composite the two matrices together, and only use one conv2d layer. So something like this:

[image]

what I want to do exactly would go too far. But can you imagine a situation where the first version would make more sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in Keras and is makes sense, if the inputs are different. To do so in keras first you need a multiple input model and you have to concatenate the outputs of the convolutional layer together.

```
input_1= Input(shape=(x,y), name='input_1')
input_2= Input(shape=(x,y), name='input_1')
c1 = Conv2D(filter_size, kernel_size))(input_1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)(input_1)
f1 = Flatten()(p1)
c2 = Conv2D(filter_size, kernel_size))(input_2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)(c2)
f2 = Flatten()(p2)

x = concatenate([f1, f2])
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[x])
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Depending on you data it could also be possible to share the convolution layers, therefore you can just define dem once and reuse them. Weights are shared in this case.

```
conv = Conv2D(filter_size, kernel_size))
pooling = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)
flatten = Flatten()

f1 = flatten(pooling(conv(input_1)))
f2 = flatten(pooling(conv(input_2)))
```