# Need help or Information about keras from tensorflow on multilayer img input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I use keras for a CNN project about img  recognition and I need help about the possibility to use multilayer image in the input.

I started with my teammate to use keras since two days, we have created our first model and our first data set but for now we use only simple layer image ! For the moment the model that we trained have a 99% accuracy on validation, we're proud, but we don't understand how to use multilayer image (18 layer images for information) as an input to our model...

Can someone help us on this or have any information/tutorial on this subject ?

Thanks in advance !

Julgi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding this right you're currently using an image of size e.g. `(100, 100)` as an input to your model?

If that's the case, you could treat each image as one channel of your input, so if you want to input 18 images, your input would have the size `(18, 100, 100)`.

Answered in the following thread:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/keras-tensorflow-cnn-with-multiple-image-inputs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582442/multiple-image-input-for-keras-application